# What is the common practice to lock file on a shared volume?

Tags: file, synchronization, locking, distributed-computing

I am writing a distributed application using Java.

I have a shared volume `V1`, which will be accessed by machine M1, and machine `M2`. machine M1 writes files on `V1`, while machine `M2` will read files from `V1`.

There will be times where machine `M2` will try to read a file which is still in the process of being written by machine `M1`.

There may also be complex cases where there are multiple writers, and multiple readers, all targeting the same file.

What are some recommended common practices in Java to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on your use case.  A common approach to handing off a file from one app to another is to write the file as .tmp and then rename the file, removing ".tmp" when done writing.  Rename is atomic.  This prevents M2 from reading the file while M1 is still writing.

However, I'm unclear/concerned about your statement regarding multiple writers.

For multiple readers, if you have several processes, each attempting to be the ONE to read/process the file, you might try having the process attempt to rename the file to .pid.  This should only succeed for one of the processes.

For multiple concurrent readers, this is generally ok, as long as none of the readers attempts to delete the file when done.  I believe the result in that case will be system dependent.

Comment: Do I need to delete the old file first if it already exist? Or can I directly renmae the tmp file and let Java handle the file replacement automatically?